# Text is transparent and not full color

Tags: text

I'm new to stack*. It seems to have a problem with my text in the fiddle underneath. Try to hover over the image.

[Fiddlelink is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ywkp1hoy/1/)

```
/*text*/

.container .head {
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
align-self: center;
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-weight: 800;
color: white;
line-height: 100px;
opacity: 0; 
width: 100%;
}

.container:hover .head , .container:hover .Description{
opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transition-delay:.2s;

}

.container .textarea {
display: block;
position: relative;
align-self: center;
}

.container .Description {
position: absolute;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
align-self: center;
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-weight: 0;
color: white;
line-height: 100px;
width: 100%;
font-variant: small-caps;
opacity: 0;

}

.item{
top: 150px;
position: relative;
align-self: center;
margin: auto;


}

.line {
    margin: auto;
    height: 1px;
    width:0%;
   text-align: center;


}
.container:hover .line {
  width:80%;
  /*background: #fff;*/
  background: red;
            -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-out;
          -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.8s ease-out;   
          margin: auto;
}
```

My text in transparent while I prefer to have it white. I tried to change the location but no result.

Comment: I know this is not perfect answer you want but you can try this: `.container:hover .grid-image {
  opacity: 0.2;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay:.3s;   
}`

Comment: Even better. Thanks a lot. I seems to overlook that one.